# How can a cylinder be rotated at any angle $\theta$ about the origin using cartesian coordinates?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

How can a cylinder be rotated at any angle $\theta$ at origin using cartesian coordinates?

What would be the equation for a cylinder (first figure) rotated about the origin?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Here is a [video for the 2d case](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPgq2AudoEo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of a cylinder in the upright position (i.e. with its axis along the vertical $z$ axis, is given by

$ \mathbf{p}^T Q \mathbf{p} = r^2 $

where $\mathbf{p} = [x, y, z]^T $ , and $r$ is the radius of the cylinder, and the $3 \times 3$ matrix is given by

$ Q = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

Now, if we rotate the axis of this center about an rotation axis $\mathbf{u}$ that passes through the origin by an angle $\theta$, then the rotation matrix $R$ will be

$ R = \mathbf{u u}^T + (I - \mathbf{u u}^T ) \cos(\theta) + S_u \sin(\theta) $

$S_u = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && - u_z && u_y \\ u_z&& 0 && - u_x \\ -u_y && u_x && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

The above formula is called the Rodrigues' rotation matrix formula.

The image of a point on the cylinder $\mathbf{p}$ is the point $\mathbf{p'}$ given by

$ \mathbf{p'} = R \mathbf{p} $

From this, we have

$\mathbf{p} = R^{-1} \mathbf{p'} = R^T \mathbf{p'} $

Substitute this in the equation of the cylinder, gives you,

$ \mathbf{p'}^T R Q R^T \mathbf{p'} = r^2 $

And this is the desired equation of the rotated cylinder.

For example, if the cylinder is rotate about the $y$ axis by $45^\circ$, then the rotation matrix will be

$ R = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 1 \\ 0 && \sqrt{2} && 0 \\ -1 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

The matrix we want is $ Q' = R Q R^T$, and equals,

$ Q' = R Q R^T = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 1 \\ 0 && \sqrt{2} && 0 \\ -1 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && -1 \\ 0 && \sqrt{2} && 0 \\ 1 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Multiplying the first two matrix from the left

$Q' = \dfrac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && \sqrt{2} && 0 \\  - 1 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && -1 \\ 0 && \sqrt{2} && 0 \\ 1 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Multiplying these two matrices, gives us $Q'$

$Q' = \dfrac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && - 1 \\ 0 && 2 && 0 \\ -1 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Now the equation of the rotated cylinder is

$ \mathbf{p'}^T Q' \mathbf{p'} = r^2 $

And since $\mathbf{p'} = [x, y, z]^T $, then the equation is

$ x^2 + 2 y^2 + z^2 - 2 x z = 2 r^2 $

**EDIT:**  However, there is an easier way to write the equation of a rotated cylinder, using its rotated axis.  Note that

$ Q = (I - \mathbf{kk}^T ) $

where $ \mathbf{k} $ is the unit vector along the $z$ axis ($\mathbf{k} = [0, 0, 1]^T$).  Therefore, the matrix for the rotated cylinder as given above is

$ Q' = R Q R^T = R (I - \mathbf{k k}^T ) R^T = I - \mathbf{a a}^T $

where $ \mathbf{a} = R \mathbf{k} $ is the rotated axis unit vector, i.e. it is the vector resulting from applying the rotation matrix to the original unit axis vector $k$.

So, now for our example, instead of all that derivation, just compute the rotated cylinder axis unit vector.  Since we're rotating the cylinder about the $y$ axis by $45^\circ$, then the new axis is

$ \mathbf{a} = R \mathbf{k} =\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} [1, 0, 1]^T $

Hence,

$Q' = I - \mathbf{a a}^T = I - \dfrac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0&& 1 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 1 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && -1 \\ 0 && 2 && 0 \\ -1 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

which is what we got earlier.  And the same equation in $x,y,z$ follows.

**EDIT 2**

As another example (a general one), suppose you rotated the vector $\mathbf{k}$ using the rotation matrix $R$, or you know the orientation of the final axis $\mathbf{a}$ in space, then you can express this vector is cylindrical coordinates as follows

$ \mathbf{a} = \begin{bmatrix} \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi) \\ \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi) \\ \cos(\theta) \end{bmatrix}$

Then the matrix $Q'$ is

$ Q' = I - \mathbf{a a}^T = \begin{bmatrix} a && d && e \\ d && b && f \\ e && f && c \end{bmatrix} $

And the equation of the cylinder will be

$ a x^2 + b y^2 + c y^2 + 2 d x y + 2 e x z + 2 f y z = r^2 $

Comment: Thanks, and what would the final equation be in terms of X,Y,r and θ then?

Comment: @RoboGio I've updated my answer to answer your question.

Comment: great, and how is the cylinder  rotated at given θ?

Comment: In my example, and to develop the equation, I've assumed that  $\theta  = 45^\circ$.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the equation actually (at the final step, reading from the matrix $Q'$ ) is $x^2 + 2 y^2 + z^2 - 2 x z = 2 r^2 $

Comment: Perfect, works!

Comment: Check my edited solution (after  **EDIT**)  for an easier method to find the equation of the rotated cylinder.

Comment: Check my second edit,  after **EDIT 2**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137157/discussion-between-robogio-and-hosam-y-hajjir).

Comment: When i try the EDIT 2, using the matrix identity a=0, d=0, e=0, d=0, b=cos(t), f=-sin(t), e=0, f=sin(t), c=cos(t). and input 45 deg. the figure i get when plotted is a cone not a cylinder at 45 deg, is the matrix identity right?

Comment: You have to compute the matrix $ I - a a^T $, this will give the entries of the matrix which are the scalars $a,b,c,d,e,f$ as shown in the solution.

Comment: Here is the final equation at any angle t: x^2*cos^2(t)+z^2*sin^2(t)-2xz*cos(t)sin(t)+y^2=r^2

Comment: the rotation is on the y axis

Comment: After rotating vector $k$ by $\theta$ about the $y$ axis, it becomes $\mathbf{a} = [ \sin(\theta), 0, \cos(\theta) ] $.  So $Q' = I - \mathbf{a a}^T = \begin{bmatrix} \cos^2(\theta ) && 0 && -\sin(\theta) \cos(\theta) \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ - \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta) && 0 && \sin^2(\theta) \end{bmatrix} $.  Therefore the equation of the rotated cylinder is  $\cos^2(\theta) x^2 + y^2 + \sin^2(\theta) z^2 - 2 \cos(\theta) \sin(\theta) x z = r^2 $, which is what you got.